# Show WAM code for a given Prolog program

Tags: prolog, warren-abstract-machine

Given a Prolog program, is there any GNU Prolog command to view the WAM code relative to that program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can [stop the compiler after any stage](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#Using-the-compiler) ( WAM, mini-assembly, assembly, etc).

To stop after WAM code is produced, use flag `-W` or `-w` with `gplc`.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.. (I don't know why my question was initially heavily downvoted..)